# Edit Twitter widget Iframe from inline to block

Tags: css, iframe, twitter

How can I force the Twitter widget to `display:block` instead of `display:inline-block`?

This is the code for the widget:

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" allowfullscreen="" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; position: static; visibility: visible; width: 300px;" title="Twitter Timeline" height="454">
</iframe>
```

And here's a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dzhoeo69/3/